# Does using closures in sml affect the speed of running code in the interactive compiler?

Tags: closures, sml, smlnj

If I have a program say:

```
fun foo x =
    let
       fun bar y = y * y
    in
       x + (bar x)
    end

    foo 123;
```

When I run this program in SML/NJ without compiling, will it have to process the declaration of `bar` each
time `foo` is called? As it would in an interpreted language.

Will it run slower than

```
fun bar y = y * y
fun foo x = x + (bar x)
foo 123;
```

Since value bindings get updated when each time you call a function this question has been brought to my mind.
Or will SML solve this in some neat way under the hood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SML/NJ in interactive mode still compiles your functions to native code. By the time you've declared `foo`, your intermediate variables have probably been optimised away. i.e. Chances are it will compile down to the same as something like `val foo = fn x => x + (x * x)`, and without the overhead of a second function, it should be faster if anything.